# Algorithm to choose a group of intervals with highest sum of their values

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, intervals

How can I solve the following problem in a way as effective as possible (perhaps linear complexity)?

As an input, I have some intervals (start, end) that holds its value (integer). There is no fixed number of intervals.
I want to find the group of intervals that are not overlaping AND the sum of their values is the highest possible (so the number of intervals doesn't matter as much as the result value).

I was thinking of implementing it as graph with evaluated edged and use perhaps Djikstra or something alike. But the problem is inserting into graph, which would take just way too much time. How can I make this better (or perhaps effective implementation of graph)?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is know as weighted interval scheduling.

The idea is to sort the intervals by their right ends and then use dynamic programming to find the weight of the heaviest subset that ends in a specific interval or before it. You can use binary search to find the rigthmost interval that can be picked before the current one efficiently. The time complexity is `O(N log N)`.

You can read more about it here: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse521/13wi/slides/06dp-sched.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Start by sorting the intervals with respect to their start. Then, define the function `f(i)` that gives the maximum sum, considering all intervals including `i` and up. This function can be calculated with a dynamic program. To specify `f(i)`, you have 2 options:

1. Include `i` and continue to the next interval that does not overlap `i`, so:
   `i.value + f(nextNonOverlappingInterval)`
2. Do not include `i` and continue with the next interval:
   `f(nextInterval)`

So overall, your function is:

```
f(i) = max(i.value + f(nextNonOverlappingInterval), f(nextInterval))
```

Set up a dynamic program to calculate `f` beginning at the last interval and propagate to the first, which then has your solution.

It is also possible to use alternative formulations of this problem to calculate from front to back or to use memoization to solve it.